# Do you feel OK?

Tags: grammar

Could you say both answers are correct or only the second one?

> Do you feel OK? Yes, I’m. (= I'm ok.)

vs

> Do you feel OK? Yes, I do.

Thanks.

Comment: We don't use contractions like _I'm_ when there isn't a word following. Likely replies are _Yes, I'm OK, Yes, I do_ or simply _Yes, thanks._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second example is fine, so lets start with that:

> - Do you feel ok?
> - Yes I do.

The first person is asking if you *feel* okay. Saying "I do" is an abbreviation of "*I do feel okay*".

There are two issues with your first example:

> - Do you feel ok?
> - Yes I'm. <--incorrect

Firstly, we don't end a sentence on a contraction. Secondly, "I'm" is a contraction of "I am", which doesn't make any sense here because you would **not** say "*I am feel okay*".

If you want to give an abbreviated reply like "I am" or "I do" then you must follow the syntax of the question.

This would be okay:

> - Are you okay?
> - Yes, I am.

(because you can say "I am okay")

There is also nothing wrong with constructing your own complete sentence if it answers the question:

> - Do you feel okay?
> - Yes, I'm okay.